# how to set file(image) on imageview

Tags: image, javafx

I want to set an image on an imageview,selecting  file from filechooser I used imageView.setImage(file), which prompts an error saying "File cannot be converted to Image"

here's my code:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane mainAnchorpane;
@FXML
private ImageView iconimageview;
private File iconimage;

 @FXML
public void iconimagebuttonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser filechooser = new FileChooser();
    iconimage = filechooser.showOpenDialog(mainAnchorpane.getScene().getWindow());
    System.out.println(iconimage.getName());
    if (iconimage != null) {
        String iconimagepath = iconimage.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(iconimagepath);
        iconimageview.setImage(iconimage);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set an `path` directly to [`setImage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#setImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-). There exists no method for [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) which accepts a file-path as parameter.

Though you can achieve the same using the constructor of ImageView which accepts a URL as a parameter

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(filepath)
```

or, creating a `Image` object using the `filepath` and then assigning it to the ImageView

```
imageView.setImage(new Image(filepath));
```

Comment: I used the constructor of ImageView to add image.But I get this error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown protocol: c
 at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1097)
 at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:598)
 at javafx.scene.image.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:164)
 at fileshare_client.fx.pkg1.UploadappUI_1Controller.iconimagebuttonAction(UploadappUI_1Controller.java:355)"  java:355 which is "imageview=new ImageView(iconimage.getAbsolutePath());"

Comment: Its because you need to append the absolute path with `file:`

Comment: this might be helpful :[Runtime error IllegalArgumentException when setting Image javafx] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646263/runtime-error-illegalargumentexception-when-setting-image-javafx)