# Runtime error IllegalArgumentException when setting Image javafx

Tags: image, url, javafx, runtime-error, invalid-url

I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown
protocol: c at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1097) 
at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:598)
at javafx.scene.image.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:164)
at fileshare_client.fx.pkg1.UploadappUI_1Controller.iconimagebuttonAction(Uploadapp‌​UI_1Controller.java:355)" java:355
```

which is

```
imageview=new ImageView(iconimage.getAbsolutePath());"
```

here's my code:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane mainAnchorpane;
@FXML
private ImageView imageview;
private File iconimage;

@FXML
public void iconimagebuttonAction(ActionEvent event) {
  FileChooser filechooser = new FileChooser();
  iconimage = filechooser.showOpenDialog(mainAnchorpane.getScene().getWindow());
  System.out.println(iconimage.getName());
    if (iconimage != null) {
      String iconimagepath = iconimage.getAbsolutePath();
      System.out.println(iconimagepath);
      **imageview=new ImageView(iconimage.getAbsolutePath());**// error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using

```
iconimage.getAbsolutePath()
```

gives you the absolute path of the file, where as the constructor expects a `file URL`

Try using

```
iconimage.toURI().toString()
```

or append `file:` to the absolute path

```
"file:" + iconimage.getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet of code I use.

```
File imageFile = new File("mountains001.jpg");
      System.out.println(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
      if (imageFile.exists()) {
         ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
         Image image = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString());
         imageView.setImage(image);
         root.getChildren().add(imageView);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

here URL has to provided in the constructor of ImageView

so the suggested code would be:

```
 @FXML
public void iconimagebuttonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    FileChooser filechooser = new FileChooser();
    iconimage = filechooser.showOpenDialog(mainAnchorpane.getScene().getWindow());
    System.out.println(iconimage.getName());
    if (iconimage != null) {
        try {
            String iconimagepath = iconimage.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(iconimagepath);
            imageview=new ImageView(iconimage.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UploadappUI_1Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```